# Como deletar uma conta?

Tags: suporte, contas-usuário

Como deletar minha conta já que possui perguntas com respostas e votos?
Pelo o que andei pesquisando bastaria apenas deixar o texto ***"please delete me"*** em minha descrição do perfíl.

Porém deixei assim por um bom tempo e a conta não foi deletada.
Voltei a colocar esse texto novamente, mas há algo a mais a ser feito?

Comment: **Relacionado:** [Excluir vinculo com uma “comunidade” especifica](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2306/3635)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Alterar a descrição do perfil para "please delete me" é metade do procedimento para isso. A outra metade é preencher o [formulário de contato](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/contact) escolhendo a opção "preciso excluir meu perfil de usuário" no campo "como podemos ajudar?". A equipe do site receberá seu pedido, mas ele pode levar alguns dias para ser atendido.

Caso seu usuário não tenha nenhuma pergunta ou resposta, você pode excluir a conta pelo link de excluir que irá aparecer no próprio perfil, ao lado do link de editar.

**Referências:** [Central de ajuda – Como exlcuir minha conta?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/deleting-account) e [How can I delete my account?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5999/how-can-i-delete-my-account)

Comment: Eu também já pedi para apagarem o meu perfil numa outra comunidade e nem tive que escrever "please delete me". O importante foi mesmo enviar o pedido para remocao.