# Como fechar o usuário, mas, deixar as respostas e as questões?

Tags: suporte

Como faço para excluir o meu usuário e deixar as respostas e questões?
Ou a exclusão é tudo ? (Usuario, Respostas e Questões) ?

Quais os procedimentos?

Comment: @bfavaretto se pode me ajudar nessa pergunta ?

Comment: Você não pode simplesmente deixar seu usuário largado de canto? Existe uma real necessidade em excluí-lo? Um belo dia se resolver voltar continuará do ponto de onde parou. Me intrometendo um pouco (sinta-se a vontade para não responder), poderia compartilhar o motivo pelo qual gostaria de tomar essa decisão? Me parece algo meio radical, talvez pudesse repensar essa situação.

Comment: @Math, obrigado pelo contato, relação maior é sobre usuários que querem ser os perfeitos no site, até já tinha discutido no meta, mas, não adianta, existem alguns que se acham os melhores e não entendem que as respostas são exemplos. A gente vai desanimando!

Comment: Achei uma informação oficial: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/deleting-account tava bem fácil. Aí você vê se é o que você quer. Não se esqueça que pode só deixar a conta inativa também.

Comment: Obrigado @Math pelo link

Comment: Obrigado @bigown

Comment: @HarryPotter acho que isso não é motivo para você excluir a sua conta. Assim como Math, eu não estou a par dos acontecimentos em relação a você, mas creio que participações com opiniões divergentes são relevantes para a comunidade, visto que o mesmo se encontra em lapidação. Se você não está satisfeito com a forma como são decididas as coisas por aqui, coloque sua opinião e tenha paciência...

Comment: @HarryPotter Eu por exemplo entro aqui poucas vezes ao dia, tiro minhas dúvidas, respondo algumas e ponto, não me dedico tanto, afinal, não ganho dinheiro pra ficar respondendo questões e moderando o site, só retribuo participando razoavelmente (esse é o meu comportamento), talvez esse deveria ser sua postura também, não gastar muita energia aqui e se dedicar mais na sua vida profissional, use o site apenas para contribuir com o seu conhecimento e compartilhar com os demais quando achar necessário.

Comment: Pô, Harry! Quiéisso, vaimbora não, sô :( . . . . . Se quiser ler sobre outras experiências (talvez) parecidas com a sua e como isso é resolvido, solucionado, acalmado (ou não!), navegue por [estes resultados](http://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=rage+quit). Sugiro fazer logout e não voltar pelo menos por uma semana, depois disso se ainda quiser embora, bueno, c'est la vie :)

Comment: Reabri a pergunta pois somente metade dela é duplicada. A outra metade, respondi abaixo.

Comment: @brasofilo sou vou deixa-los, para que vocês tenham a plena certeza que são um grupo muito forte. Mas existem pessoas que nos fazem pensar e acreditar que a realidade é bem diferente, vivenciando a realidade para nos humilhar e deixar a gente pior. Obrigado pelo seu contato e boa sorte!

Comment: @Orion tem razão, obrigado mesmo pela dica e preocupação, mas, existem pessoas aqui que não merecem a nossa intervenção, são perfeccionistas e usam isso como proposito para nos humilhar. Se não acredita mas a pessoa continua enchendo o saco (nesse momento) e o moderador apagou todas as minhas explicações e deixou a deles isso não é certo porque estou sendo tratado diferente do outro OP (o moderador é o @utluiz)

Comment: Bom, o mantra aqui é "foco no conteúdo e **não** nas pessoas". Se tem alguém fazendo bullying contra você peça a intervenção dos moderadores através de um sinalizador personalizado. Enfim, talvez você queira reincarnar com seu nome verdadeiro e começar do zero. Em todo caso, boa sorte também!

Comment: @brasofilo não vou voltar com nome verdadeiro, e boa sorte para você também

Comment: Pena que se foi embora, mas a vida é mesmo assim, não aguentou a perseguição que eu e todo mundo sabe que existia. Eu mesmo denunciei alguns casos em que perseguiram ele.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O procedimento para remoção de contas já foi explicado em *[Como deletar uma conta?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1525/como-deletar-uma-conta)*. Quanto a manter as perguntas e respostas, esse é o procedimento padrão quando um usuário é removido (salvo exceções como spammers).

Segundo explicado em *[Difference between a deleted user and a "destroyed" user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88994/difference-between-a-deleted-user-and-a-destroyed-user)*, quando um usuário é removido, ocorre o seguinte:

- Perguntas e respostas com pontuação negativa são excluídas
- Perguntas e respostas com pontuação zero ou posivita são mantidas
- O nome do autor nas perguntas e respostas é substituído por "userN" (onde N é o ID do usuário excluído)
- A conta e o perfil do usuário são excluídos
- Todos os votos dados pelo usuário excluído são anulados

A exclusão de contas é um procedimento que *geralmente* não é desfeito (tecnicamente até pode ser desfeito, mas acredito que dependa de intervenção manual no banco de dados). Portanto, pense bem antes de solicitar isso.

Answer (score 4):

<sup>*ficou muito grande para ser um comentário</sup>

Eu não acompanho as suas tags de expertise (C#, PHP, etc) então não sei do quê nem de quem você está reclamando, mas meu conselho é: Foque nos pontos positivos do site e tente ao máximo se entender com as pessoas, faça seu ponto de vista e tenha empatia pelo ponto de vista dos outros. Se não consegue se entender de maneira alguma tente deixar aquilo que te desanima de lado.

Tem um famoso ditado que diz:

> Corrija um sábio e o fará mais sábio, corrija um ignorante e o fará teu inimigo.

Saiba identificar quem é sábio e quem é ignorante, não gaste seu tempo com o segundo caso, e tome cuidado para se enquadrar sempre no primeiro.

"Sábio" e "ignorante" são papéis que as vezes assumimos temporariamente, não são uma condição eterna. Não estou dizendo que você se encaixa em um deles, não me entenda mal, o que quero dizer é que algumas vezes somos rígidos e ásperos, e ao olhar uma situação com mais calma vemos que poderíamos ter aprendido com aquela situação ao invés de termos nos stressado, assim como faz o sábio.

Outro ditado diz:

> Não tome decisões drásticas enquanto estiver com raiva

O resumo de tanta filosofia é que em minha opinião você deve olhar o lado bom do site; e, não apague sua conta enquanto não tiver total certeza de que é a coisa certa a se fazer, deixa ela aí quietinha enquanto esfria a cabeça.

Como disse logo no início, não sei exatamente do que se trata sua angustia, portanto minha resposta foi meio que genérica, se preferir, dê mais detalhes em um novo tópico para tentarmos resolver o seu problema, que ocasionalmente pode também ser o mesmo problema de várias outras pessoas, que entretanto não se manifestaram.

Comment: Eu acho que isso é uma resposta pro comentário, e não pra pergunta. Mesmo pro meta, acho que "isto não responde ao que foi perguntado". (nota: eu vi seu asterisco no começo, por isso nao negativei nem dei flag de "não é uma resposta", mas acho um precedente estranho, que incentiva este comportamento de "perguntar uma coisa pra provocar outra").

Comment: (não que tenha sido intenção do HP este tipo de resposta, mas outras pessoas podem ver e achar que é assim que funciona)

Comment: Legal da sua parte a preocupação mas, eu só comprovo que a questão é jeito a forma e isso não vai ser resolvido, porque, a mentalidade vem do SO, mas obrigado vlw

Comment: @Bacco quando terminei de escrever eu sabia que ia acabar infringindo uma regra, mas como já tinha escrito achei melhor seguir em frente para ver o que ia dar, no final das contas eu pensei no velho jargão: `estamos interessados em atrair pessoas, e não afastar`. Não gosto de ver as pessoas se afastando do site pelo problema citado pelo OP e acabei deixando o lado emocional prevalecer, se preferirem eu apago, ou se preferir sinta-se a vontade para negativar, afinal ficará claro que essa resposta não é para ser um hábito. De qlqr forma, essa pergunta é duplicada e eu já sinalizei como tal.

Comment: @Math Não tenho intenção de negativar (quando eu acho que devo negativar, não faço muita cerimônia hehehe). Como disse, considerei o comentário que vc pos no começo. Apenas achei bom mencionar como um alerta mesmo, para "não passar em branco" como coisa normal. Pra falar a verdade, "Corrija um sábio e o fará mais sábio, corrija um ignorante e o fará teu inimigo" quase ganhou um +1 meu, pois é a essência de quase todos os grandes desentendimentos do SO que eu tenho visto. Só não upei por justamente não ser uma resposta pra essa pergunta em específico.

Comment: @Bacco sem problemas :) vou dormir e amanhã vejo o que decidiram por aqui, como o OP já leu mesmo talvez eu devesse apagar, seila. Amanha eu vejo.

Comment: Acho que o ditado completo é *"Não faça promessas quando estiver feliz, nem tome decisões quando estiver com raiva"*

Comment: Grande sábio @brasofilo, acho que é isso mesmo que você falou, mas passei perto, vai, rsrs