# Recurso para visualizar pelo menos as respostas de usuários excluídos

Tags: novo-recurso, status-recusado

Percebam que nessa imagem o usuário user6026, não tem o link, porque, esse usuário pediu sua saída do SO. Pergunta-se:

Seria relevante pelo menos um link para visualizar as suas respostas?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O usuário fechou a conta então... Como quebra-galho dá pra pesquisar no Google `user6026 site:pt.stackoverflow.com`, retorna 510 resultados pra mim. Tentei consultar via [SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com/) e via [API](http://api.stackexchange.com), mas não deu em nada. Bem interessante o pedido de novo-recurso.

Answer (score 8):

Esse pedido de novo recurso foi [status-recusado](/questions/tagged/status-recusado) no Meta Stack Exchange, vide [Make searches for user:xxx work for deleted users as well](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/191964/185667).

As principais razões são expostas nos comentários da pergunta por Nick Craver e ChrisF:

- [Não temos essa informação, nós deletamos os usuários *de verdade*, não há *soft-delete*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191964/make-searches-for-userxxx-work-for-deleted-users-as-well#comment598112_191964)
- [O nome de usuário é anonimizado quando a conta é deletada usando "User" + "Id". Por que essa informação não pode ser usada para achar o post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191964/make-searches-for-userxxx-work-for-deleted-users-as-well#comment598149_191964)

  :... [Nada disso é posto no índice de pesquisa, e isso ainda é uma pesquisa parcial, não uma ocorrência específica de um número inteiro.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191964/make-searches-for-userxxx-work-for-deleted-users-as-well#comment598281_191964)
- [Não há planos para fazer o soft-delete dos usuários, isso é uma mudança colossal com muito pouco benefício e um custo enorme na performance.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191964/make-searches-for-userxxx-work-for-deleted-users-as-well#comment743076_191964)

Em [uma das respostas](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/220031/185667) vemos que para pesquisar no SEDE, é necessário usar o `OwnerDisplayName` em vez do `OwnerUserId`: [**query para ver os posts de um usuário deletado**](http://data.stackexchange.com/pt/query/165820/posts-by-a-deleted-user).

Tem uma outra query interessante também, com os [**top users deletados**](http://data.stackexchange.com/pt/query/154922/top-deleted-users), onde vemos que esse [usuário foi a maior baixa](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1603/como-fechar-o-usu%C3%A1rio-mas-deixar-as-respostas-e-as-quest%C3%B5es) até agora:

[image: top deleted users no SOPT]

Answer (score 7):

O @brasofilo já apontou as opções existentes para se recuperar os conteúdos desses usuários: SEDE e Google. Eu sou contra esse tipo de pesquisa, pelo seguinte motivo: se um usuário é excluído, ele deixa de existir. Não vejo por que permitir que suas postagens sejam recuperadas em conjunto. Em certos casos, isso pode até dar margem a perseguições – ao ler várias postagens de um mesmo usuário, é possível identificar seu estilo, entre outras informações, que podem ter sobrado em links, por exemplo. Por mim, os posts dele poderiam até ser transferidos para o usuário [Comunidade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/comunidade), assim as postagens de todos os usuários excluídos ficariam embaralhadas.